# How to Recover Data From My Dead Laptop

Tags: laptop, ssd

I have a laptop that no longer shows signs of life when plugged in. It has files I wish to recover, but I'm not sure how. The laptop is an Acer Aspire E5-576G-5762, with an 256 GB M.2 SSD keyed M+B. (Please correct me if anything said in this post isn't phrased correctly, I'm rather new to this.)

Comment: You will need a USB M.2 enclosure that supports the SSD.  You first will have to determine if it's a NVMe or SATA M.2 device, so you can determine, which USB M.2 enclosure you need.

Comment: If OS was Windows and bitlocker encryption was enabled and you do not have the bitlocker key then save your money - the data is gone. If the drive was not encrypted then getting the data back should be simple as described by Ramhound! good luck

Comment: Putting the ssd in a usb case is likely the way to go if you dont have bitlocker. If you do, have a look at https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/625710/wont-boot-black-screen-please-help-e5-576g-5762 - this long thread has a lot of steps/things to try to get the system working so you can pull the data off. (before that though, have you tried leaving it on charging overnight?

Comment: use recoverit or norton undelete for windows

Comment: @Petepf recovery tools aren't relevant, his issue is with access to the drive (and the drive should have the data, it wasn't deleted)

Comment: @davidgo even with BitLocker he can connect the drive to another PC if he has the password or recovery key (recovery key can be found in the Microsoft account if connected to one)

Comment: Any idea *why* the laptop no longer works? Was it dropped? Dead battery or power supply? Windows update that went bad? If it can be fixed, it might be easier to recover data with SSD still in PC.

Comment: Going on an addition to what @DrMoishePippik said.  Booting Hiren's Boot or LinuxLive and getting to the drive from there might be an option if the machine isn't junked.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik A couple of years ago, it got left in a toaster oven and melted slightly, but otherwise, it still worked correctly. About a year ago, it randomly wouldn't charge for some time but would work again. I've looked for damage on the cord but found nothing. I've tried leaving it charging, still nothing. I haven't been able to figure out exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It can't boot from a Linux CD/USB because it doesn't show any signs of life. Neither the charging or power lights turn on.

Comment: "it randomly wouldn't charge for some time but would work again." Then the issue is almost certainly with the battery and/or charging circuit, often easily fixed. Before I'd take out the SSD, I'd try a new battery, and *carefully* look at the connectors for the power supply, to see if part puled loose from the PCB. Resoldering that would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a simple `COUNTIFS`.

You create a header column with the car types and a first row with the years:
[image]

Then you under in the first cell (at the BEV:2026 intersection) the following (where `B$1` is the cell that has ***BEV***, and `$A2` is the cell with the 2026):

```
=COUNTIFS($M:$M,B$1,$K:$K,$A2)
```

Then drag fill the formula right to all the types, and then (having all four selected) drag fill down for all the year.

---

If you want to make it more automated... and do not need a list of ALL YEARS (even when there were no cars sold on the list) you can auto generate the column header and first row:

- In `A2` use: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(K:K,K:K<>""))`
- In `B1` use: `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(M:M,M:M<>"")))`

And then use the following for the formula in `B2` (and fill drag across and down to a bunch of rows and columns, it will result in empty where the column or rows aren't in range):

```
=IF(OR(B$1="",$A2=""),"",COUNTIFS($M:$M,B$1,$K:$K,$A2))
```